# For semi-supervised learning, is more pseudolabels always better than less pseudolabels?

Tags: machine-learning, ratio, semi-supervised-learning, labeling

Let's say I have a labeled dataset $L$ and unlabeled dataset $U$, where $U \gg L$. Suppose I focus on a subset of $U$ called $u$ and generate a subset of $u$ I'll call $u_L$ that consists of pseudolabels for $u$ that I've generated using [Tri-training](https://ruder.io/semi-supervised/). Suppose $U$ is so large, that depending on the amount of datapoints I can choose to make up $u$, I can make $u_L$ virtually as large or as small as I want, from $10$ datapoints to $100$ to $1000$ to $1000000$ if I so wished, all from generating the pseudolabels from tri-training.

If I want to eventually train a model using $L \cup u_L$, is there any reason I'd want to restrict the size of $u_L$? Generally speaking when it come to ML, the more representative data the better the model, but in this circumstance I'm not sure. I can't seem to find anything about this.

Comment: This is a good question (+1) I had it myself for a while when I started playing with SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semi-Supervised Learning (SSL) while not admitting it, emphasises the need to monitor the learning procedure via [learning curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_curve_(machine_learning)). As such, while we do not actively restrict the size of $u_L$ it should "restrict itself"; this might happen because we cannot successfully label any new unlabelled data or because we have actual performance degredation. Saito et al. [*Asymmetric Tri-training for Unsupervised Domain Adaptation*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.08400) (2017) has a really nice investigation of this phenomenon (see Fig. 4) where we observed clear plateauing in performance. That's why you correctly note that neither the original tri-training reference by Zhou & Li (2005) [*Tri-Training: Exploiting Unlabeled Data Using Three Classifiers*](https://doi.org/10.1109/TKDE.2005.186) or other standard self-training references make any references to a "max-ratio". (Maybe you have already checked the short monograph [*Introduction to Semi-Supervised Learning*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-031-01548-9) (2009) by Zhu & Goldberg but I found it very readable and helped me have a more unified view of the subject). That said, from a practical perspective it makes sense to constantly test your model performance on real data too. Ultimately all the success stories of self-driving cars, sentiment analysis, etc. get a lot of real data feedback. As Oliver et al. (2018) say in [*Realistic Evaluation of Deep Semi-Supervised Learning Algorithms*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.09170):
"*SSL is most likely the right choice for practitioners: (...)
When the labeled dataset is large enough to accurately estimate validation accuracy, which is necessary when doing model selection and tuning hyperparameter*".
Similarly, be aware that one of the classes might be easier to "soft label" and indirectly lead us to an imbalanced learning setting, French et al. (2017) [*Self-ensembling for visual domain adaptation*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.05208) walked into that one and had to correct it via modifying their loss functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I'm reading correctly, you're saying model performance will have a tendency to plateau as $u_L$ increases? And I'd do well to keep an eye on learning curves to know when this plateau starts to occur? Also, what do you mean by "soft label"?

Comment: And just to be clear, what's the best way to go about generating learning curves for SSL? Similar to SL? Keep two chunks of the labeled dataset for validation and test sets, train on the remaining labeled data and $u_L$ of varied size, and see how the models perform as you increase $u_L$?

Comment: Cool, I am glad I could help. Yes, it should plateau. By "soft label" I mean the one from the tri-training (or any other self-train procedure) as opposed to the one from a real-world labelling procedure. Yes, similar to SL but as the comment from Oliver et al. suggests the original labelled dataset needs to be large enough accommodate that. Note that $u_L$ is learned only on the training sample, note the validation/testing sets.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Any heuristics/ways for knowing if my original labeled is large enough to start soft labeling with a reliable val and test set? Not sure if Oliver et al. gives any advice about that but I can check..

Comment: Pleasure! :) I honestly do not have a good heuristic on this as this will be both application and performance-level dependent. I use some generic "minimum sample size for external validation" papers from time to time but I do treat them with a very large grain of salt, a recent one I *plan to read* is [*Minimum sample size for external validation of a clinical prediction model with a binary outcome*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/sim.9025) (2021) by Riley et al. references therein should also be helpful.

Comment: In the case of SSL, what should be my estimator for the learning curve? I'm wondering if I'm overthinking this. Should I just make sure my labeled data is sufficiently large by plotting learning curves using `sklearn` or something with *some* estimator, and if the training performance has plateaued I know I'm ready to start tri-training with this appropriately-sized $u_L$?

Comment: I would use the most relevant for our problem. Assuming we are doing classification an obvious one would be AUC-ROC ($c$-index) as it is a reasonable (i.e. semi-proper) scoring rule, so we examine discrimination but other estimators like AUC-PR might be good too. Yes, correct, cause if we could get our "sufficient performance level"  without $u_L$ we wouldn't bother for it. :)

Comment: That makes sense in terms of scoring, but, for instance, `sklearn` requires an estimator input, that has `predict` and `fit` methods, so it has to be some kind of model. I assume it doesn't matter which one I use as long as it can suit the needs of my problem? If the model performance plateaus, I know my labeling work is done?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confusing myself. A training curve can be used before SSL to show that labeling more data is unlikely to improve model performance, and a training curve can be used on different sizes of $u_L$ to find out what size of $u_L$ is beneficial.